# Pandas dataframe, how to create a new totals column containing values based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
>>> df

         Dr Name           Type   Total  Fund Total
0        Debtors  Balance Sheet  200.00        0.00
1           Bank  Balance Sheet  352.25      100.00
4   General Fund           Fund -100.00     -252.25
5  Building Fund           Fund    0.00     -300.00
```

I want a new column to be created, being filled with either `Totals or` Fund Totals.

If the `Type` is `Balance Sheet` I would like the `Total` column to be used - and if the `Type` is `Fund` the `Fund Total` to be used. To produce this:

```
>>> df

         Dr Name           Type   Total  Fund Total   Grand Total
0        Debtors  Balance Sheet  200.00        0.00        200.00
1           Bank  Balance Sheet  352.25      100.00        352.25
4   General Fund           Fund -100.00     -252.25       -252.25
5  Building Fund           Fund    0.00     -300.00       -300.00
```

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to ask a question it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```py
df["Grand Total"] = df.where(df["Type"] == "Fund")["Fund Total"].fillna(df["Total"])
```

With `df.where` I extract the column `Fund Total` only where the type is Fund (other rows will be `nan`. Then `fillna` fills those `nan` using another column (`Total` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `where` from `numpy`:

```
import panda as pd

df['Grand Total'] = np.where(df['Type'] == 'Fund', df['Fund Total'], df['Total'])
print(df)

# Output
         Dr Name           Type   Total  Fund Total  Grand Total
0        Debtors  Balance Sheet  200.00        0.00       200.00
1           Bank  Balance Sheet  352.25      100.00       352.25
4   General Fund           Fund -100.00     -252.25      -252.25
5  Building Fund           Fund    0.00     -300.00      -300.00
```

Comment: Quick question, I'm using pd.read_clipboard() to read the original text into a DataFrame, but the values in my columns are off when I use ```df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}')```. Is there a way you are reading in the original data cleanly?

Comment: No I copy/paste into an editor and I insert manually a space between `Fund` and `-100` :) lol